# Auto size column depending on max size in multiple rows in css/angular

Tags: css, angular, forms, layout, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to achieve that the width of the label column of a horizontal form is equal on every row of the form depending on the size of the largest label. I hope this images makes it clear:

[Example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkccW.jpg)

All the columns with the labels inside should auto size to the red line.

This is the markup that I use to get the form in the screenshot:

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group form-row">
    <div class="col-6 row">
      <label for="1" class="col-auto col-form-label">Label 1:</label>
      <div class="col">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 row">
      <label for="2" class="col-auto col-form-label">Label 2:</label>
      <div class="col">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group form-row">
    <div class="col-6 row">
      <label for="1" class="col-auto col-form-label">Label 1 row 2:</label>
      <div class="col">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 row">
      <label for="2" class="col-auto col-form-label">Label 2 much longer on row 2:</label>
      <div class="col">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group form-row">
    <div class="col-6 row">
      <label for="1" class="col-auto col-form-label">Label 1 is even longer on row 3:</label>
      <div class="col">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 row">
      <label for="2" class="col-auto col-form-label">2:</label>
      <div class="col">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Is this even possible with bootstrap 4 or other css? I'm using it in a Angular app so maybe that could bring some help.

Comment: use your bootstrap. set the `width`  of the `label` and the `div` surrounding the `input` fields by using `col-xs/sm/md/lg-XX`

Comment: That would make the label column way to big, the goal is to use col-auto on the label column so no unnecessary space is lost there. It should auto size on the content of the label and be equal on all the rows in the same column

Comment: `col-md-auto` is sizing based on width of the content, not on the content around it or a percentage of overall width.  That is where your issue lies.  If you want to use auto width, set a width that will cover the longest text (for all appropriate rules where you are using `col-md-auto`).

Comment: That is what I'm doing now but that means trial and error on every form which is tedious work on a large data application. For that reason I'm looking for a dynamic/automatic scaling way instead of manually setting the max width. Maybe this is something that is impossible since I never see it in examples. The strange thing is that it's very common in winforms/wpf applications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could arrange labels and inputs into their own columns.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body class="container">
  <form class="row">
    <div class="flex-column d-flex">
        <label>label 1</label>
        <label>label 2</label>
        <label>...long label 3...</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col flex-column d-flex">
        <input type="text">
        <input type="text">
        <input type="text">
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

But you'll be battling to keep the heights correct because the "rows" are now independent.